# Do all first posts really go through review?

Tags: discussion, review

Honestly, who lets a post like this slip?

[Skipping the second automatically generated quote in QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646513/regarding-simple-operation-of-qt-creator-skipping-the-second-automatically-gene)

Perhaps it is me, but for me it is hardly better than random words. I have not the slightest idea what his problem is and what he is asking. What to do with posts like this?

Comment: I would ask for the user to clarify the question... but I admit, it seems nonsensical...

Comment: To answer your question in the title, [yes, they do](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2867925).

Comment: I believe all first posts do go through the review queue, but because of caching, they may not show up in the queue right away (so obviously, a post gets traffic *before* showing up in the queue). Also, [some people don't take reviews seriously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/218097) and simply click through the post without reading it.

Comment: I managed decipher the question and I have edited it so hopefully it is a little clearer now.

Comment: @AnnaLear, then Kon should rephrase the question that we all can understand it. He did not seem to have a problem with it. Btw..thanks for your edit. I do not require perfect English. Not everybody is a native speaker. English is a second language for me, too. So I make quite a few mistakes myself. But when a text becomes totally incomprehensible it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Greenflow I understood the question as it was written. Perhaps Kon did too. (Although Kara made further improvements to clarify things, which is always good.)

Comment: **Now** it gets clearer. And if more people edit it, it is soon in the community wiki. :-D

Comment: "I can't seem to find a way to get past the second one without having to move my hand to use the arrow keys". Ironically, how many hand moves and clicks did it take to log in SO, click ask question, type his subject & post and come back to check answers? He could have done lots more..of.. whatever... it is you do in C++

Comment: Why are people down voting this? Are we disagreeing with the fact mentioned in the answer that all first posts go through the queue? You guys are pathetic.

Comment: @ColeJohnson a lot of the early down-votes probably came with the first version of the question, which had some ... phrasing issues. Even after the edit, the framing of the question itself is not the most useful way to address a potentially valid issue, and is probably still garnering a few down-votes due to it still falling under the latter parts of "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" in some people's opinion.

Answer (score 8):

What to do?

- Edit (or at least a suggested edit) if it can be salvaged, or
- Flag if there isn't much that can be done.

If I'm remembering right, the review queue doesn't hold the post for review as in "it's not displayed until someone reviews it" - it just queues a list of first-posts for people to check.

As a side note, as frustrating as it is to find questions like that, moderating the tone will help you get a better response.

Comment: Ah, ok. I did not know this: **"it's not displayed until someone reviews it"**. At least something positive I got from this post. :-)

Comment: @Greenflow Well, AninJr is saying that's *not* the way the system works...

Comment: @Greenflow - that's missing the "the review queue **doesn't** hold the post for review as in" that came before the part you're quoting; and the "it just queues a list of first-posts for people to check" part that came after.

Comment: @AnonJr Don't worry. I understood you perfectly well. Just sloppy quoting.

Comment: @Greenflow just checking :)